# Select Must Return only one row against every id

Tags: sql, select

I'm using the below query to get results. The purpose of the query is to get the latest sales_amount of every customer, but when the sales are two or more in the given date range, the query returns all the records, how I can get only the latest records against the id. The same id should contain only one row against each id.

```
SELECT id,
       Max(date),
       sales_amount
FROM   customer
WHERE  date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-15'
       AND id = 1001
GROUP  BY id,
          sales_amount;
```

Comment: You need to use a windowing function -- what platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row number in a sub query to give you an ordering and then just pick the first one.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, date, sales_amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) as RN
  FROM   customer
  WHERE  date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-15'
       AND id = 1001
) sub
WHERE RN = 1
```

Note if you want to do it for all customers then this is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, date, sales_amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) as RN
  FROM   customer
  WHERE  date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-15'
) sub
WHERE RN = 1
```

That will give you the most recent row for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have included the ID in teh group by clause, all ID's will be returned.

Comment: Group by is used to group all the duplicates.

Comment: yes - but every row is likely to have a unique ID meaning you have grouped by an identifier

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
   SELECT id,
   Max(date),
   sales_amount
   FROM   customer
   WHERE  date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-15'
   AND id = 1001
   GROUP  BY id,
      sales_amount
   ORDER BY date DESC 
   LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this still have the group by so it will have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from (

    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() as Rn, 
       id,
       Max(date),
       sales_amount
FROM   customer
WHERE  date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-15'
       AND id = 1001
GROUP  BY id
order by max(date)
)
where Rn = 1
```